# Battery Balancing Board Equilibrium Current?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, balancing, cell-balancing

I just bought some balancing boards for a Bluetooth speaker project and realized after the fact there are two different equilibrium current options. I bought both the 2S and 3S versions as I haven't settled on how much voltage I want to supply to the speaker amp yet.

Needless to say I bought the 300mA version and my pack is only around 3000mA. Two questions, first is "what is equilibrium current"? Second, can I use this board with my project or do I need to get the 100mA version?

> Equilibrium current: 100mA, suitable for 2000-4000mAh battery pack
>
> Equilibrium current: 300mA, suitable for 8000-12000mAh battery pack

[2S 3S 4S Li-ion Lithium Battery 2 3 4 Cell Charger Balance Circuit Board 100mA 300mA 4.2v Battery BMS Charging Balanced balncing](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/33035939865.html)

Thank you,
Martin

Comment: Your link takes you to a sign in page for ali express. That's the first problem. The 2nd problem is that decent pdf data sheets are required and not some reputation-challenged selling site that probably won't have a data sheet and sell stuff that is sourced from non-reputable manufacturers.

Comment: The link has been updated.

Comment: **The 2nd problem is that decent pdf data sheets are required**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, equilibrium current is balance current.  This is the amount of current that will be bled from a cell that is over the balance point.  In order to reach balance in a reasonable amount of time, larger packs need to be balanced at higher current levels.

Comment: Ok so it seems I should have gone with the 100mA version than?

Comment: Either will work just fine for you battery.